# How do I install a security certificate for an alias (domain pointer) in DirectAdmin?

Tags: redirects, https, security-certificate, certificate-generation, directadmin

I have the following problem: I have 2 domains: `domain1.example` and `domain2.example` (domain pointer) => `domain1.example`.

Previously, I used Let's Encrypt to create SSL for both in DirectAdmin and it was OK. But DST Root CA X3 Expiration error made my Let's Encrypt alert and I bought paid SSL.

I bought ssl for `domain1.example` but `domain2.example` doesn't have SSL.

How do I install SSL for the domain pointer? I'm using DirectAdmin version 1.61.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectAdmin 1.52.0 started supporting HTTPS for domain pointers.  They [say](https://www.directadmin.com/features.php?id=2026):

> SSL certificates used in the VirtualHost/server will be the ones from the master domain the pointer is created under.
> To avoid SSL Certificate errors, you'll need to ensure that the pointer is also in the master domains certificate.
> LetsEncrypt can do this for you, just an extra checkbox from the list.

So to make it work you would need to get a subject alternate name (SAN) certificate that has both `domain1.example` and `domain2.example` covered in the **same certificate**.   When you add the certificate to `domain1.example` DirectAdmin would automatically use it for `domain2.example` as well.   It sounds like you had LetsEncrypt give you a SAN certificate that covered both your domains.  You would have to do the same thing with your new certificate provider.

To use a its own separate certificate, you would need to configure the domain differently.  You wouldn't be able to use DirectAdmin's domain pointer feature.  [This forum](https://forum.directadmin.com/threads/ssl-certificates-and-domain-pointers.32487/) has some ways of doing so.  One user created a new domain and uses a frameset to forward it (although you should be able to set up a redirect somehow.)   Another user uses a custom virtual host template.  That thread says that you might have to create the domain on its own IP address, but that thread is old and that shouldn't be the case at this point.  At this point certificates should work in virtual hosts without their own IP address on pretty much every web server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DirectAdmin than you are not talking about redirection as Patrick Mevzek interpretated it, but about using a domainname as an alias whilst rewriting the url to the actual website domain it points to.

In DirectAdmin you can not have both a paid SSL (TLS) certificate for a domain and a free (Let's Encrypt) certificate for a subdomain or alias.

What you can have is:

1. a paid certificate for both
2. a free certificate for both
3. a domainpointer that's created as a new main domain and manually pointed towards the actual websitedomain. In which case you can use Let's Encrypt on the domainpointer and a paid cerificate on the actual website domain.

The last option involves a CNAME record in the DNS records. A bit more technical overhead but it grants you your exact wish. :)

Answer (score 0):

> But DST Root CA X3 Expiration error made my Let's Encrypt alert

Expiration of this root certificate does not make Let's Encrypt certificates not work, you just have to take it into account and configure your servers appropriately, or just generate new certificates with the alternate chain.
Please see the FAQ at the end of https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html for appropriate remediation depending on your case.

> How do I install SSL for domain pointer?

Everyone should stop using the term "SSL", because the proper term is TLS and that is since 1999, and "domain pointer" means nothing in general (not a standard term).

If I understood your question right you want to **redirect** (that is the proper HTTP term) one URL to another, the source being your "naked" (or root or apex) domain? If so, you don't have any other solution, you need a certificate for this domain, no matter from which CA.

You can have one certificate with both domains in it, or two separate certificates. Technically both cases will work the same way.

Comment: "domain pointer" appears to be terminology used by DirectAdmin: https://www.knownhost.com/wiki/control-panels/directadmin/how-to-set-pointer-domain

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Anyone is indeed free to invent new terminology. But it doesn't mean it is any good (domain pointer certainly isn't) nor useful, as there is already a term for it, redirection, so pointless to create another one.